# How to iterate through a database of foreign keys to split items into sections

Tags: php, loops, iteration

This is how my database is structured:

**product_types**

name (text field)

description (text field)

**menu**

name (text)

price (text)

product_type_id (foreign key to product types table)

---

*What I want to be able to do is to loop through the product_type table and present all the items that are in menu table with that product type.*

I want to do this so I can split items into sections, for example the product_type table will contain items such as 'food', 'drink'.

This is my code so far which all it does is get every item from menu table:

```
<?php
    $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM menu");
    // print " Query returned ". $result->num_rows . " rows ";; 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?> 

    <p><? echo $row["name"]; ?></p>
    <p><? echo $row["description"]; ?></p>
    <p><? echo $row["price"]; ?></p>
    <hr>
<?php 
    }; 
?>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, my programming is a lot about readability. One of the biggest pet peeves of mine is to see poorly written code with neither tab structure nor consistent indention style. For the example below, you will see that I have used an associative [Multidimensional Array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) to organize our menu items by products types. We structure our query using [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to combine the two tables using `product_type_id`. In MySQL, `JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. `INNER JOIN` is used with an `ON` clause, `CROSS JOIN` is used otherwise. The menu items have already been ordered in the query, if you do not order your result in the query I would suggest sorting the array via [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), since we are using the product type as an index. Lastly, since we are integrating HTML into our PHP, I would strongly suggest using [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for the control structures. As a fallback, I can check if the array is empty to determine if we had any results. Default text is always better than a blank page:

```
<?php
    /* Fetch Menu Items */
    $menu_items = array();
    $sql = "SELECT `product_types`.`name` AS 'product_type', `product_types`.`description`, `menu`.`name`, `menu`.`price` FROM `menu` JOIN `product_types` ON `product_types`.`id` = `menu`.`product_type_id` ORDER BY `product_types`.`name`";
    $query = $connection->query($sql);
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $menu_items[$row['product_type']][] = $row;
    }
?> 

<?php if(!empty($menu_items)): ?>
    <?php foreach($menu_items as $product_type => $items): ?>
        <h2><?php echo $product_type; ?></h2>
        <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
            <p><?php echo $item['name']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['description']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['price']; ?></p>
            <hr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Sorry. No menu items to display at this time. Please check back soon!
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I am trying to use your response to solve the problem but the only thing that is printing out is the product_type - but it is looping around twice so it is getting the right amount of items - just not showing them

Comment: Don't worry, I've sorted it. - Just needed to change '$row['name']' to $item['name'] - Thanks for the answer

Comment: @smith_05_bird Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the code. I try reserving $row for extracting data from queries, so that it doesn't get overwritten in an `include()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT m.name, m.price, p.id as productTypeId, p.name as productType, p.description FROM menu inner join product_types p on m.product_type_id = p.id order by p.id");
$productType = null;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ( $row['productTypeId'] != $productType ){
        $productType = $row['productTypeId'];
        echo "<h2>$row['productType']</h2>";
    }

    ?>

    <p><? echo $row["name"]; ?></p>
    <p><? echo $row["description"]; ?></p>
    <p><? echo $row["price"]; ?></p>
    <hr>
    <?php
};
```

Comment: You're calling an object off an associative array.